# Looking for a simple way to truncate a string in c#

Tags: c#

I used the following:

```
t.Description.Substring(0, 20)
```

But there is a problem if there are less than 20 characters in the string. Is there a simple way (single inline function) that I could use to truncate to a maximum without getting errors when the string is less than 20 characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
t.Description.Substring(0, Math.Min(0, t.Description.Length));
```

Somewhat ugly, but would work. Alternatively, write an extension method:

```
public static string SafeSubstring(this string text, int maxLength)
{
    // TODO: Argument validation

    // If we're asked for more than we've got, we can just return the
    // original reference
    return text.Length > maxLength ? text.Substring(0, maxLength) : text;
}
```

Comment: I like this a lot as I already use some extension methods for strings.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
t.Description.Take(20);
```

**EDIT**

Since the code above would infacr result in a char array, the proper code would be like this:

```
string.Join( "", t.Description.Take(20));
```

Comment: That will return an `IEnumerable<char>` - to get it as a string you'd need `new string(t.Description.Take(20).ToArray())` which starts being pretty unwieldy - and is relatively inefficient.

Comment: Jon - As you can see I realized myself, and I have to say that the first line of code looks better than before my edit ;). Thanks for reminding me that there is a string constructor that takes a char array as a argument.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 string myShortenedText = ((t == null || t.Description == null) ? null : (t.Description.Length > maxL ? t.Description.Substring(0, maxL) : t));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another:

```
var result = new string(t.Description.Take(20).ToArray());
```